# Push notification seen when I background the app

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push

I'm seeing something very strange, and I'm hoping someone here can help me. Anytime I close/background my iOS app, the last push notification sent to that app via UrbanAirship pops-up at the top of the screen.

I've setup push notifications for my iOS app using UrbanAirship, and its associated libraries. I'm using the latest library from UA (1.3.3), and I believe I've configured everything correctly.  I've gone over the basic documentation multiple times, and I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary that I can tell.

In my `AppDelegate`, I'm not doing anything with the UA libraries in the functions `applicationWillResignActive` or `applicationDidEnterBackground`, so I'm not certain why backgrounding the app would trigger this notification to come up. The documentation doesn't state that anything needs to happen in those functions. In the function `applicationWillTerminate`, I am correctly calling `[UAirship land]`, but this issue isn't popping up when the app is terminated.

More data: I'm not actually seeing a new notification in the Notification center on my phone.  I'm just seeing the message pop-up again, as if it were new.

This issue is perplexing, and if anyone can offer some insight or assistance with it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Just as an aside, these days ApplicationWillTerminate isn't called. Your app just gets sent a SIGKILL. Perhaps the urban airship API is saving the notifications?

Comment: Interesting thought. That's definitely possible -- I should probably contact their support to ask this same question on top of asking SO :P.